# Strange behaviour of mongo-db $inc

Tags: mongodb, grails

In my grails project I'm using the code like:

```
def contextsToFlush = [ 'contexts.a_b_c':1, 'contexts.a_b':1, 'contexts.a':1, total:1]
MyDomainClass.collection.update( [ _id:this.getId() ], [ $inc:contextsToFlush, $set:[ lastFlush:lastFlush ] ], false, false, WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED )
```

sometimes the `total` field does not get incremented:

```
{
  "_id" : "52fce967144b39a7c11c1c54",
  "contexts" : {
    "a_b_c" : NumberLong(1),
    "a_b" : NumberLong(1),
    "a" : NumberLong(1),
 },
 "lastFlush" : NumberLong("1392307968375"),
 "total" : NumberLong(0),
 }
```

Can it be, that `$inc` operator treats document fields and subdocument fields differently?

Comment: I don't know whatever language that is, but it helps to log the actual request (e.g. using the mongodb embedded profiler) so you can inspect what is really sent to the database. The fact that `total` has no quotes looks suspicious to me: `['contexts.a_b_c':1, 'contexts.a_b':1, 'contexts.a':1, total:1]` vs. `['contexts.a_b_c':1, 'contexts.a_b':1, 'contexts.a':1, 'total':1]`

Comment: no quotes is totally valid for such constructs in groovy